# Why flex: 1; behaves diffrently from flex: 1 1 auto or flex-grow: 1?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was taking a course of html and css and the teacher explained that flex property is the shorthand of flex grow,shrink and basis.
Why using **flex:1;** on every children makes them to behave diffrently from **flex: 1 1 auto;**  or **flex-grow:1;**. And another question, why if i call **flex: 1** in the parent container this isn't inherited by the children.

[Pen link](https://codepen.io/ClaudiuAlexandru/pen/LYmJxev)

```css
div {
  width: 1366px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #009e2a;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #c9663e;
  gap: 30px;
}

.element1 {
  background-color: red;
  /*     flex-grow: 1; */
  flex: 1;
}

.element2 {
  background-color: blue;
  /*     flex-grow: 1; */
  flex: 1;
}

.element3 {
  background-color: navy;
  /*     flex-grow: 1; */
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="element1">ana are mere djskahdkahk</p>
  <p class="element2">
    da chiar are mere dasldsakjdfhaskfjgsaj dkjashdkasghkd dkjsahdkja, fajkfa.hdkjash
  </p>
  <p class="element3">ce tar dalkjjd klashe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex): *"One-value syntax: the value must be one of: a <number>: In this case it is interpreted as flex: <number> 1 0; the flex-shrink value is assumed to be 1 and the flex-basis value is assumed to be 0."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) : `flex : 1` is short for `flex: 1 1 0` not `flex: 1 1 auto`.

With `flex:1`, `flex-grow` is 1, `flex-shrink` value is assumed to be 1 and the `flex-basis` value is assumed to be 0.

Also read up this [bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#formal_definition), the property is not inherited.

Comment: Tip: No need to keep commenting CSS properties, just write the one that you want in the end. They will override https://codepen.io/tushar8/pen/NWMerLP?editors=0110